# Only first variable from array is pasting to range of cells

Tags: excel, vba

I am attempting to copy an array of labels to a range of cells, however, only the first variable is being copied over to the Range. In this case, cells `B4:B17` are all being set as "Number of Properties". I have attached my code below. Thank you.

```
'Format and Set Values for Labels
Dim labels As Range
Set labels = Sheet1.Range(r.Offset(RowOffset:=2).Address & ":" & _
        r.Offset(RowOffset:=15).Address)

labels.Interior.ColorIndex = 0
labels.Font.ColorIndex = 0
labels.Font.Bold = True
labels.HorizontalAlignment = xlLeft
labels.NumberFormat = "General"

labels.Value = Array("Number of Properties", "", "", "Name", "Address", "City/State", _
            "Purchase Date", "Holding Period", "", "Units", "Rentable SF", _
            "Avg SF Per Unit", "Parking Spaces", "Parking Ratio")
```

Comment: A 1D array it is 'seen' by VBA having only columns. So, it must be transposed, but take care to resize the area where to drop the array content, to exactly the array number of elements.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use Application.Transpose like that

```
labels.Value = Application.Transpose(Array("Number of Properties", "", "", "Name", "Address", "City/State", _
            "Purchase Date", "Holding Period", "", "Units", "Rentable SF", _
            "Avg SF Per Unit", "Parking Spaces", "Parking Ratio"))
```

And you can use variables for easier use later if needed

```
Dim x
x = Array("Number of Properties", "", "", "Name", "Address", "City/State", _
            "Purchase Date", "Holding Period", "", "Units", "Rentable SF", _
            "Avg SF Per Unit", "Parking Spaces", "Parking Ratio")
labels.Value = Application.Transpose(x)
```

Comment: Awesome, worked great thank you. Definitely going to store in variable and then use count to use that for the offset so its not hard coded at 15

Comment: How do I count the amount of variables in that array?

Comment: `Ubound(x)` for 1D arrays, `Ubound(x, 1)` for 2D array rows and  `Ubound(x, 2)` for columns.

Comment: You can use UBound like that `MsgBox UBound(x) + 1`